# Dynamic Block Nested For Condition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Hello Experts I am trying to build a terraform module for cloud function in which i can create multiple cloud functions at once. I am dynamically creating the event trigger but not sure if my approach is right. The dynamic event trigger is the part where i am getting stuck. Can someone validate my approach.  I have included the code below :

**Main.tf**

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "event-function" {
  for_each = var.cloudfunctions
  project              = local.test_project
  region               = lookup(local.regions,"use1")
  name                 = format("clf-%s-%s-use1-%s-%s", var.domain, var.env, var.use_case, each.key)
  description          = format("clf-%s-%s-use1-%s-%s", var.domain, var.env, var.use_case, each.key)
  #source_directory     = "${path.module}/${each.value}}
  #bucket_force_destroy = var.bucket_force_destroy
  entry_point          = each.value.entry_point
  runtime              = each.value.runtime
  #vpc_connector        = "projects/${var.host_project}/locations/${var.region}/connectors/${var.vpc_connector_prefix}-${var.environment}-test"
 
dynamic event_trigger {
    for_each = [ for i in each.value.event_trigger : lookup(local.event_trigger,i.event_name,i.resource) ]
    content {
        event_type          = event_trigger.value.event_type
        resource            = event_trigger.value.resource
      }
  }
```

**Variables.tf**

```
variable "cloudfunctions" {
  type = map(object({
  runtime       = string
  event_trigger = list(object({
    event_type = string
    resource = string

   }))
  }))
  default = {}
}
```

**Locals.tf**

```
    42.event_trigger = flatten ([
    43.     for i,n in var.cloudfunctions :[
    44.     for event in n.event_trigger :{
    45.        event_type = event_type
    46.     resource   = resource
    
           }
         ]
      ])
    
    }
```

Comment: Okay i have found what was wrong with the approach :

Comment: Post an answer with your solution or delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

To use the dynamic event trigger block you need :

```
dynamic event_trigger {
for_each = each.value.event_trigger 

content {
   event_type = event_trigger.value.event_type
   resource   = event_trigger.value.resource
}

}
```

This worked fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. Can you add context so that your question and answer help others?